# Using glDrawElements on OS/X (OpenGL 3.2 core profile)

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to port some OpenGL 3.2 code from Windows to OS/X 10.8 (using GLFW core profile), but get a INVALID_OPERATION (glError()) when I call the glDrawElements. The glDrawArrays functions works fine, so my shaders are initialized ok.

The following snippet explains well what I am doing. Any idea of what I do wrong?

```
struct Vertex {
 vec2 position;
 vec3 color;
};

void display() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    mat4 projection = Ortho2D(-15.0f, 15.0f, -15.0f, 15.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, projection);

    glBindVertexArray(shapeVertexArrayBuffer);

    mat4 modelView;

    // upper left
    modelView = Translate(-7,+7,0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, rectangleSize); // renders correctly

    // upper right
    modelView = Translate(+7,+7,0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    GLuint indices[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,0};
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices); //INVALID_OPERATION

    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

void loadGeometry() {
    vec3 color(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertex rectangleData[rectangleSize] = {
        { vec2( 0.0,  0.0 ), color },
        { vec2( 5.0, -5.0 ), color },
        { vec2( 5.0,  0.0 ), color },
        { vec2( 0.0,  5.0 ), color },
        { vec2(-5.0,  0.0 ), color },
        { vec2(-5.0, -5.0 ), color }
    };
    shapeVertexArrayBuffer = loadBufferData(rectangleData, rectangleSize);
}

GLuint loadBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount) {
    GLuint vertexArrayObject;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute  , 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)sizeof(vec2));

    return vertexArrayObject;
}
```

Comment: *GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a **non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array** or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.* Check these two, please, especially the one with emphasis. If you used glDrawArrays, you might forget to clear it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I believe that that it is a bug on OS/X. You can see my full example here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6024335/glDrawElementsProblem.cpp (almost self-contained). As you can see I'm not using any element array buffer, but only CPU array. I'm under the impression that both techniques should work in 3.2 core profile, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are suppose to create an indices buffer after your vertex buffer.

```
GLuint elementBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &elementBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then you can call `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);`

Comment: well, it should still work with a cpu array. maybe he should make sure that no array is bound: glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0); probably also glDisableClientState(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER).

Comment: Had the same issue: this solved it! Indeed it appears that even on my somewhat recent MBPr, OSX cannot work with a CPU array of indices for glDrawElements*.